# How can you get unittest2 and coverage.py working together?

Tags: python, code-coverage, unittest2

How can you get `unittest2` and `coverage.py` working together?

In theory something like

```
coverage run unit2 discover
```

should work, but it currently just errors out.

If you are a `nose` user that will be the equivalent of `nosetests --with-coverage`.

Comment: I get 

    `$ coverage run unit2 discover
    Coverage.py warning: No data was collected.
    No file to run: 'unit2'`

I'm running Python 2.7 on OS X 10.6.8.

Answer (score 47):

Try:

```
coverage run -m unittest discover
```

works for me.

Answer (score 5):

This must be specific to your installation since it works fine for me

```
coverage run unit2 discover
```

to generate the coverage information then

```
coverage html
```

to generate the an HTML report (one of several reporting formats), and

```
open htmlcov/index.html
```

to see the results.

(Answering this because this is a top ghit for "unittest2 coverage" and I don't want people put off by the lack of any answer.)

Answer (score 3):

I am running Windows and encountered the same problem.

```
$ coverage run unit2 discover
No file to run: 'unit2'
```

I suspect this is related to differences in how the system path and python path are handled on various operating systems (I'm guessing Andrew is running linux?). Regardless, `coverage run` takes a `-m` option which allows you to run a module rather than a script.  This is what I use:

```
coverage run -m unittest2 discover
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you have multiple versions of `coverage` installed, use

```
coverage2 run -m unittest discover
```

or

```
coverage3 run -m unittest discover
```

to specify which one you're going to run.